# Is there a difference between `%`-format operator and `str.format()` in python regarding unicode and utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, string, encoding, string-formatting

Assume that

```
n = u"Tübingen"
repr(n) # `T\xfcbingen` # Unicode
i = 1 # integer
```

The first of the following files throws

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 82: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I do `n.encode('utf8')` it works.

The second works flawless in both cases.

```
# Python File 1
#
#!/usr/bin/env python -B
# encoding: utf-8

print '{id}, {name}'.format(id=i, name=n)
```

---

```
# Python File 2
#
#!/usr/bin/env python -B
# encoding: utf-8

print '%i, %s'% (i, n)
```

Since in the documentation it is encouraged to use `format()` instead of the `%` format operator, I don't understand why `format()` seems more "handicaped". Does `format()` only work with `utf8`-strings?

Comment: When you did `u'{id}, {name}'.format(id=i, name=n)` what did you observe?  Note that the formatting string is a Unicode string `u'...'`.  Please add that to your examples and comment on it.

Comment: Thank you S.Lott, this was it. I understand now where my fault was. `'{id}, {name}'` was a utf-8 string (defined by the *magic line* `# encoding: utf-8`) and `n` was in unicode. It is not possible to "concatenate" them. That is why `n.encode('utf8')` worked. Right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `string.format` while you don't have a string but an `unicode` object.

```
print u'{id}, {name}'.format(id=i, name=n)
```

will work, since it uses `unicode.format` instead.